# Oracle , Existe una función para obtener automaticamente el primer dia del mes de la fecha actual?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

mi pregunta es si existe una función en Oracle que realice lo 
siguiente de forma directa ?

```
   Select to_date('01/'||to_char(sysdate,'mm/yyyy'),'dd/mm/yyyy') 
   from dual :
```

De antemano gracias por la atención brindada.

Answer (score 3):

Con este `select` se obtiene el primer día del mes actual:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,’MM’) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: Gracias Yeiro por tu comentario, buscando mas información de tu respuesta si funciono select trunc(sysdate, 'MM') from dual;
 
TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')
-------------------
01/09/2018

Comment: Me alegra te haya servido amigo, cierra la pregunta y calificame Saludos!